# JavaScript image crop / rectangle select on image

Tags: javascript, html, image, crop

I have a question regarding JavaScript. I want something like this for a project:

[image]

Basically, I want some kind of a rectangle selection within a picture. I already have the PHP for processing it later. I just need to get the X & Y position of the top/left corner of the crop. Is this possible in JS+HTML? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you want the user to move the mouse so he can select the part of the image ?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant. Except I only want to get the coordinates of the crop's top/left position. Because then I'll pass the info to my PHP script.

Comment: try to use `z-index` in css. i am sure it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible.
You can create for the crop selector : a div element, set its border and make its position absolute.
And you make it follow the mouse position with $('#myImage').mousemove();

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3kCPP/2/

And here is a code you can test :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="info">Click on the image !</div>


<div id="myContainer" style="margin-left:140px;margin-top:40px;">
    <div id="myCropSelector" style="position:absolute; border:1px solid red; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
    <img id="myImage" src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5340/8990232431_9f7a93d3ca.jpg" alt="myImage"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $myCropSelector = $("#myCropSelector");
    var $myImage = $('#myImage');
    var $myContainer = $('#myContainer');

    var isMouseOnImage = function (mouseEvent, $image) {
        var imageOffset = $image.offset();
        return event.pageX >= imageOffset.left
            && event.pageX <= imageOffset.left + $image.width()
            && event.pageY >= imageOffset.top
            && event.pageY <= imageOffset.top + $image.height();
    }

    /**
     * Return the location inside the document and the size of the cropSelector
     * if it was supposed to be centered on the mouse location.
     * {
          pageX: absolute screen position
          pageY: absolute screen position
          imgX:  relative position to the image
          imgY:  relative position to the image
          w:     width of the crop
          h:     height of the crop
     * }
     }
     */
    var getCropInfo = function (mouseEvent, $cropSelector, $image) {
        var pageX = mouseEvent.pageX - $cropSelector.width() / 2;
        var pageY = mouseEvent.pageY - $cropSelector.height() / 2;
        var imageOffset = $image.offset();
        return {
            pageX: pageX,
            pageY: pageY,
            imgX: pageX - imageOffset.left,
            imgY: pageY - imageOffset.top,
            w: $cropSelector.width(),
            h: $cropSelector.height()
        };
    }

    $myContainer.mousemove(function (event) {

        // if the mouse is on the image
        if(isMouseOnImage(event, $myImage)) {

            // we center the crop selector
            var cropInfo = getCropInfo(event, $myCropSelector, $myImage);
            $myCropSelector.css({'top': cropInfo.pageY, 'left': cropInfo.pageX});
        }
    });

    $myContainer.click(function (event) {

        // if the mouse is on the image
        if(isMouseOnImage(event, $myImage)) {
            var cropInfo = getCropInfo(event, $myCropSelector, $myImage);
            var infoToDisplay = "";
            infoToDisplay += "x:" + cropInfo.imgX + "<br />";
            infoToDisplay += "y:" + cropInfo.imgY + "<br />";
            infoToDisplay += "width:" + cropInfo.w + "<br />";
            infoToDisplay += "height:" + cropInfo.h;
            $("#info").html(infoToDisplay);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to happen when I click the image in your example.

Comment: The top part of the page displays the crop selector information.

Answer (score -1):

try to do this by using css.

this is so simple:

**html**

```
<div>
    <div id="crop"></div>
<img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Creative/Abstract/abstract-310v.jpg" height="350" width="400" id="img" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#crop{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    margin-left:200px; 
    position:absolute;
}

#img {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
   margin-top:-110px;
}
```

see this in this fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BqkB3/1/)

Comment: What about the Javascript part that make the crop selector move ?